# How to watch several tags using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my HTML code:

```
<textarea id="uno-1" name="1"></textarea>
<textarea id="uno-2" name="2"></textarea>
```

And here is my JS code:

```
$("[id^=uno]").keyup(function() {
    clearTimeout(typingTimer);
    if ($("[id^=uno]").val) {
        typingTimer = setTimeout(function() {
            $.get("/someUrl", {
                text: $("[id^=uno]").val(),
                id: $("[id^=uno]").attr('name')
            });
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

The point is that text is saved automatically by sending it to GET Url right after typing it. However the problem is that it always catches only the first text area even if I type text in the second text area. I need to send GET attributes respectively. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Use `$(this).val` instead `$("[id^=uno]").val`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you are always referencing all the inputs and you are not using the current only.

```
$("[id^=uno]").keyup(function() {
    clearTimeout(typingTimer);
    var input = $(this);  //reference the current textarea
    if (input.val().length) {  //not sure what your check was, but it was strange
        typingTimer = setTimeout(function() {
            $.get("/someUrl", {
                text: input.val(),  //use the variable we set about
                id: input.attr('name')
            });
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank a lot! This is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, use a class to group your elements:

```
<textarea id="uno-1" class="uno" name="1"></textarea>
<textarea id="uno-2" class="uno" name="2"></textarea>
```

Then you can use that class along with the `this` keyword in the event handler to refer to the element which raised the event.

```
var typingTimer;
$(".uno").keyup(function() {
    clearTimeout(typingTimer);
    if (this.value) {
        typingTimer = setTimeout(function() {
            $.get("/someUrl", {
                text: this.value,
                id: this.name
            });
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is your use of `$("[id^=uno]").val()` and `$("[id^=uno]").attr('name')`.

`$("[id^=uno]")` selects both fields.

[`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val) then returns the value from the first field.

To fix this use `$(this)` within the callback.

---

`setTimeout` will create a new function scope as well, so be sure to capture the value of `this` from `keyup(function () {` using something along the lines of:

```
self = this;
//or
$this = $(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use $(this)

```
$("[id^=uno]").keyup(function() {
    clearTimeout(typingTimer);
    if ($(this).val) {
        typingTimer = setTimeout(function() {
            $.get("/someUrl", {
                text: $(this).val(),
                id: $(this).attr('name')
            });
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```